Definition of assembly in literature versus Assembly class
According to Microsoft Learn,

Assemblies take the form of executable (.exe) or dynamic link library (.dll) files, and are the building blocks of .NET applications.

According to the ECMA-334 specification, 7th edition,

assembly – one or more files output by the compiler as a result of program compilation

So, both definitions state that an assembly is a file. However, I can create an Assembly im memory, e.g. with the code
System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
CompilerResults r = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp").CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, "public class A {public static int B=7;}");
Assembly a = r.CompiledAssembly;

With the GenerateInMemory flag set, there will not be a DLL or EXE on disk.
So, is there a difference between an assembly and Assembly objects, or are the definitions just sloppy? Why do we need the term "file" in the definition of an assembly at all?

I would say it's an example of "Same word in different context has slightly different meaning". Also, that which is in memory is probably the same 'data' as it would be on disc ... Seems "sloppy", yes. But again: even some scientific terms are not exempt from taking on different "flavors" based on context.

Files don't have to be on disk, right?

Wiki: "Where files contain only temporary information, they may be stored in RAM". But yeah, the Assembly class "Represents an assembly": it's an interface to query an assembly. It obviously isn't just the raw bytes of an assembly, it's got methods and data structures to load and query the contents of an assembly

Would "one or more files (possibly virtual)" be clearer?

@canton7: A temporary file is still created with the help of a file system driver and you would see it in Explorer, even if it weren't written to the hard drive. I doubt that the assembly class does that.

@RaymondChen: for the ECMA standard, why not simply remove the term "files" and have "output by the compiler as a result of program compilation"? And for MSDN "Assemblies are the building blocks of .NET applications. On disk, they take the form of executable (.exe) or dynamic link library (.dll) files."

Don't fixate on the Assembly class -- that's only a representation of an assembly, as it exists in either a file, a stream, or a byte array. Just as a Person class isn't a real, living person in your computer. It sounds like the core of this confusion is whether a "file" can exist in memory, before it's written to disk (and still be called a "file" at that point)? I think most people would argue that it can, for the purely practical reason of not needing a second term for "A file which is in non-volatile memory"...

@shingo: then, when is a file a file? If I have a char[] in memory, that's not a file to me, it's a buffer. If I have a RAM disk, it's in RAM of course, but it still uses a file system driver. If I download a file from the Internet, it may not be a file while it is streamed, but it becomes a file when the stream is saved.

... From context I think it's obvious that an "in-memory assembly" is the contents of an assembly file, but held in memory and not written to disk

@canton7: if the Assembly class represents an assembly, and assembly is defined as a file, then we should not be able to create an Assembly object without a file. Otherwise the representation is broken. My point is: why do we need the term "file" in the definition of an assembly at all?

@canton7: is it really the contents of a file in memory? An EXE and DLL file will need a PE header. I can't say for sure whether an  Assembly object has such a PE header, I recall that it doesn't.

Having the definition of an assembly be based on files, people do problematic stuff, such as asking the Assembly for its Location, wondering why it can be an empty string or throw an exception.

What's the motivation behind this? Are you genuinely confused about what's happening, or is there some other reason?

@canton7: I was reading a scientific work (not public) in computer science and it was refering to assemblies as files saved on disk. This didn't match my understanding, since I knew assemblies could be created in memory. But when I looked up the sources, it seems I can't even blame the student. My problem with this is that we again have someone with a wrong understanding of assemblies. The student certainly learned something, but didn't learn it correctly.

I read that in ECMA-335, the description of assembly has been changed to "An assembly is a set of one or more files deployed as a unit". Combined with the definition in ECMA-334, it should be understood that an assembly is a unit (a result of program compilation) generated by a compiler from one or more files. The word "output' in ECMA-334 seems to be the predicate.

@shingo: or in the glossary (page 6, 6th edition of ECMA-335): "assembly: A configured set of loadable code modules and other resources that together implement a unit of functionality." doesn't mention files at all.

That way you create the assembly "in memory" in fact also used to create a file on a disk somewhere, by the way. But in any case, I think you're taking the "file" term as a bit too narrow; it doesn't imply any persistent storage. File always meant just an organization system, usually a very simple "this is a bunch of data in order". That's where you get "file system" from too - it just means a system for filing data. There's no requirement that a file in a file system represents some physical data stored on a disk or something. "File" doesn't really mean much (and that's a good thing).
